# Rails session variables: different behavior on development and production

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, session-variables, production-environment

I'm trying to set a simple boolean value in a session variable. The value is set from a check box through javascript:

View:

```
<script>
  function set_session_var_my_value()
  {
    if(document.getElementById('my_value').checked){
      $.get('/set_session_var?my_value=true');
    }
    else{
      $.get('/set_session_var?my_value=false');
    }
  }
</script> 
...
<li> <a class="checkbox">My Var<%= check_box_tag('my_value', '1', (session[:my_value]=='true'), :onclick => 'set_session_var_my_value();') %></a></li>
...
```

Route:

```
get "/set_session_var", :to=>"user_session_vars#my_value"
```

Controller:

```
class UserSessionVarsController < ApplicationController
  def my_value
    session[:my_value] = params[:my_value]
    render :json => {"response" => "OK"}
  end
end
```

I'm using devise for authentication. In the application controller, after sign in I set the variable to false as a default value:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  ...
  protected
    def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
      session[:my_value] = false
      root_path
    end

end
```

When running in development the variable is being set and I can see and use its value in others views, but in production it doesn't work. I'm using Apache with Phusion Passenger. I've tried commenting protect_from_forgery but it still doesn't work.

**Update Jan 6 '14**

I found that when I clear the cache in the browser (ctrl + shift + supr), the ajax request works properly for two request calls and then `session[:my_value]` is set to its last value in the next calls. I have tried calling `window.applicationCache.update();` in the ajax call with the same results.

Comment: I would begin by checking if the AJAX request is being made in production by looking at the Network tab in your browser's developer console

Comment: UserSessionVarsController#my_value is being called, I proved adding a line in this method to write to log the value of session[:my_value], and it writes always false.

Comment: Reading this might help you resolve the error on your own: http://nofail.de/2013/10/debugging-rails-applications-in-development/

Comment: unless you foresee the user using multiple devices at the same time, why not just use client side local storage?

Comment: I've tried using cookies[:my_value] with the same results.

Comment: @hector, you said you checked the value of `session[:my_value]` and it was always `false`. But wouldn't that be a symptom that the AJAX request is not being made by the client, as I suggested?

Comment: @depa, during the AJAX request session[:my_value] is set to the value sent but it seems that in next requests the value is set to false:
[link](http://snipt.org/BGad7)